# Unable to Post Dropdown Values Added at Runtime in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, razor

For some reason I'm having trouble getting option values I add to an ASP.NET MVC dropdown at runtime to post.

In this case, I'm adding options to the dropdown at runtime using jquery.
This is what I have so far:

The Razor HTML:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(sc => sc.SelectedComponents, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SelectedComponents", @name= "SelectedComponents", size = "5", multiple = "multiple" })
```

The relevant portion of the model:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SelectedComponents { get; set; }
```

Also, I can't get the posted values added at runtime to appear in the Forms Collection when I look in the controller action.

Can anyone suggest the best way to handle this particular situation?

Thanks much,

Pete

---

More information:

I'm trying to implement a simple solution using "BeginCollectionItem" to post added items at runtime when I submit the Razor Form.

In the main view I have this to display the partial view:

```
 @foreach (var components in Model.selectedComponents)
            {
                @Html.Partial("SelectedComponents", Model)
            }
```

The Partial View looks like this:

```
@model  blah.blah.RequestViewModel

@using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("selectedComponents"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Component" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3">Selected Components:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedComponents, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "SelectedComponents", @name = "SelectedComponents", size = "5", multiple = "multiple" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-3">
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The relevant portion of the viewmodel looks like this:

```
 public class RequestViewModel
 {
     public IEnumerable<string> selectedComponents { get; set; }
 }
```

I simply want to post a list of strings that are added at runtime using jquery.  This part is working and is not shown.

The controller that I'm posting to looks like this:

```
  public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase[] files, RequestViewModel data)
        {
}
```

Comment: Not related, but your `new { @id = "SelectedComponents", @name= "SelectedComponents" }` are pointless - the method already adds the correcr `name` and `id` attributes and `name=...` does nothing anyway. And if you want a `<select multiple>`, then you use `@Html.ListBoxFor()`, (which adds `multiple = "multiple"`), not `DropDownListFor()`

Comment: Show the relevant code. How are you adding the options? What is the POST method? Why are using `FormCollection` instead of binding to your model?

Comment: Based on your edit, your `BeginCollectionItem()` makes no sense. If you look at the `name` attribute of the html you are generating, you will see `<select name="selectedComponents[xxxx].selectedComponents" .... >` (where `xxx` is a `Guid`) which binds to a model containing a `public IEnumerable<T> selectedComponents { get; set; }` property where `T` is a model containing a `public IEnumerable<string> selectedComponents { get; set; }`  property. Its not clear what you are trying to do with this code.